# highlight the word in the string, if it contains the keyword

Tags: php

how write the script, which menchion the whole word, if it contain the keyword? **example:** keyword "fun", string - the bird is funny, result - the bird is * funny*. i do the following

```
     $str = "my bird is funny";
     $keyword = "fun";
     $str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
```

but it menshions only keyword.  my bird is **fun**ny

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/\w*?$keyword\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
```

`\w*?` matches any word characters before the keyword (as least as possible) and `\w*` any word characters after the keyword.

And I recommend you to use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote) to escape the keyword:

```
preg_replace("/\w*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\w*/i", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
```

For Unicode support, use the *u* flag and `\p{L}` instead of `\w`:

```
preg_replace("/\p{L}*?".preg_quote($keyword)."\p{L}*/ui", "<b>$0</b>", $str)
```

Comment: @sberry2A: PCRE regular expressions are greedy by default. That means a quantifier is expanded to the maximum of possible repetition. The `?` is making the quantifier ungreedy so it matches as least repetitions as possible. (See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: How to find  exact match word & highlight it?

Comment: @NitinKarale take a look at this awesome solution http://www.aidanlister.com/2004/04/highlighting-a-search-string-in-html-text/

Comment: @gumbo Unfortunatelly preg_quote is not recommended to use for preg_replace in the doc http://php.net/preg_quote - it doesn't escape html tags like </script>, and you receive an error like Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'c'

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

```
 $str = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keyword}[a-z]*)\b/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
```

Example:

```
$str = "Its fun to be funny and unfunny";
$keyword = 'fun';
$str = preg_replace("/\b([a-z]*${keyword}[a-z]*)\b/i","<b>$1</b>",$str);
echo "$str"; // prints 'Its <b>fun</b> to be <b>funny</b> and <b>unfunny</b>'
```

Comment: @codaddict i know, that in regular-expressions $ means the end of something.
but what does it mean in your script? and why { simbols, instead of (?

Comment: @Syom: This is only for PHP to distinguish between variables and literal string content in double quoted string declarations: `"$foobar"` will be evaluated to the value of `$foobar` while `"($foo}bar"`/`"${foo}bar"` will be evaluated to the value of `$foo` concatenated with `bar`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing for further information.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
$str = "my bird is funny";

$keyword = "fun";
$look = explode(' ',$str);

foreach($look as $find){
    if(strpos($find, $keyword) !== false) {
        if(!isset($highlight)){ 
            $highlight[] = $find;
        } else { 
            if(!in_array($find,$highlight)){ 
                $highlight[] = $find;
            } 
        }
    }   
} 

if(isset($highlight)){ 
    foreach($highlight as $replace){
        $str = str_replace($replace,'<b>'.$replace.'</b>',$str);
    } 
} 

echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Use `str_ireplace()` instead of `str_replace()` which is case-insensitive version of `str_replace()`

Answer (score 0):

Here by am added multi search in a string for your reference

```
$keyword = ".in#.com#dot.com#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9#one#two#three#four#five#Six#seven#eight#nine#ten#dot.in#dot in#";

$keyword = implode('|',explode('#',preg_quote($keyword)));

$str = "PHP is dot .com the amazon.in 123455454546 dot in scripting language of choice.";

$str = preg_replace("/($keyword)/i","<b>$0</b>",$str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks Walery Strauch

Answer (score 0):

Basically, since this is HTML, what you have to do is iterate over text nodes and split those containing the search string into up to three nodes (before match, after match and the highlighted match). If "after match" node exist, it must be processed too. Here is a PHP7 example using PHP DOM extension. The following function accepts preg_quoted UTF-8 search string (or regex-conpatible expression like `apple|orange`). It will enclose every match in a given tag with a given class.

```
function highlightTextInHTML($regex_compatible_text, $html, $replacement_tag = 'span', $replacement_class = 'highlight') {
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
    $d->loadHTML('<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head>' . $html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);

    $process_node = function(&$node) use($regex_compatible_text, $replacement_tag, $replacement_class, &$d, &$process_node) {
        $i = preg_match("~(?<before>.*?)(?<search>($regex_compatible_text)+)(?<after>.*)~ui", $node->textContent, $m);
        if($i) {
            $x = $d->createElement($replacement_tag);
            $x->setAttribute('class', $replacement_class);
            $x->textContent = $m['search'];
            $parent_node = $node->parentNode;
            $before = null;
            $after = null;
            if(!empty($m['after'])) {
                $after = $d->createTextNode($m['after']);
                $parent_node->replaceChild($after, $node);
                $parent_node->insertBefore($x, $after);
            } else {
                $parent_node->replaceChild($x, $node);
            }
            if(!empty($m['before'])) {
                $before = $d->createTextNode($m['before']);
                $parent_node->insertBefore($before, $x);
            }
            if($after) {
                $process_node($after);
            }
        }
    };

    $node_list = $xpath->query('//text()');
    foreach ($node_list as $node) {
        $process_node($node);
    }
    return preg_replace('~(^.*<body>)|(</body>.*$)~mis', '', $d->saveHTML());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Search and highlight the word in your string, text, body and paragraph:

```
<?php $body_text='This is simple code for highligh the word in a given body or text';  //this is the body of your page
$searh_letter = 'this';  //this is the string you want to search for
$result_body = do_Highlight($body_text,$searh_letter);    // this is the result with highlight of your search word
echo $result_body;            //for displaying the result
function do_Highlight($body_text,$searh_letter){     //function for highlight the word in body of your page or paragraph or string
     $length= strlen($body_text);    //this is length of your body
     $pos = strpos($body_text, $searh_letter);   // this will find the first occurance of your search text and give the position so that you can split text and highlight it
     $lword = strlen($searh_letter);    // this is the length of your search string so that you can add it to $pos and start with rest of your string
     $split_search = $pos+$lword; 
     $string0 = substr($body_text, 0, $pos); 
     $string1 = substr($body_text,$pos,$lword);
     $string2 = substr($body_text,$split_search,$length);
     $body = $string0."<font style='color:#FF0000; background-color:white;'>".$string1." </font> ".$string2;
     return $body;
    } ?>
```

Comment: This is a very simple example , u can just copy paste and change according to ur requirement..

Comment: your solutions contains the same problem the OP is asking, it only highlights the characters matching the keyword, not the word containing the characters.