# regex to higlight the word part-by-part if it contain the keyword

Tags: php, regex

i've asked same question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword), but now i need to higlight the keywortd in another way, then other part of word. example will be helpful i think

```
$str = "i like programming very much";
$key = "gram";
```

i need to get something like *pro* **gram** *ming*

```
$str = "i like <span class='first'>pro</span><span class='second'>gram</span><span class='firs'>ing</span>"

why preg_replace("/([^\s]*?)(".preg_quote($key).")([^\s]*)/iu","<span class="first">$0</span><span class="second">$1</span><span class="first">$2</span>",$str);
doesn't work?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors, the first group is $1 and not $0 and so on. And you embeded ".

so, instead of :

```
preg_replace("/([^\s]*?)(".preg_quote($key).")([^\s]*)/iu","<span class="first">$0</span><span class="second">$1</span><span class="first">$2</span>",$str);
```

You have to do :

```
preg_replace("/([^\s]*?)(".preg_quote($key).")([^\s]*)/iu","<span class='first'>$1</span><span class='second'>$2</span><span class='first'>$3</span>",$str);
```

Comment: fixed. thanks much. but why in some cases it starts from 0, another time from 1?

Comment: As far as i know, $0 means the whole pattern matching. But i'm not sure this is true for every flavor of regex.

Answer (score 1):

You're in PHP, so consider something like:

```
$words = explode(' ', "quick brown fox");
$out = array_map(process, $words);
return join(' ', $out);
```

and define

```
function process($word) {
    $p = strpos($word, 'gram');
    if ($p === FALSE) return $word;
    /// take apart pieces with substr and friends, reformat in HTML, and return them
    $left = substr($word, 0, $p);
    $match = substr($word, $p, strlen('gram'));
    $right = substr($word, $p+strlen('gram'));
    return some_function_of($left, $match, $right);
}
```

A little more effort, but it does what you want.