# is this possible with file get contents?

Tags: php

Hello stackoverflow if i have this log

```
 16:23:36 - [Turks] dannys 
 16:23:55 - *LOCAL* [Turks] stop! 
 16:24:08 - *LOCAL* [Turks] stop 
 16:24:11 - *LOCAL* [Turks] no attack 
 16:24:28 - *LOCAL* [Turks] stop! 
 16:24:35 - *LOCAL* [Turks] hey 
 16:24:37 - *LOCAL* [Turks] dur amk 
 16:24:52 - *LOCAL* [Dannys] fottiti 
 16:25:04 - *LOCAL* [Turks] hey 
 16:25:11 - *LOCAL* [Turks] hey 
 16:25:12 - *LOCAL* [Turks] money 
 16:25:36 - Turks <img=ico_swordtwo> Dannys 
 16:25:43 - [Turks] you noob 
 16:26:09 - *LOCAL* [Turks] I'm giving your money! 
 16:26:19 -  <img=ico_headshot> Turks 
 16:26:46 - Dannys has joined the game with ID: 416519 
 16:26:46 - Dannys has joined the game with ID: 416519 
 16:26:46 - Dannys has joined the game with ID: 416519 
 16:26:46 - Dannys has joined the game with ID: 416519
```

Currently this is my code

```
<?php
$now = ($_POST['date']);
$file = "logs\server_log_".$now.".txt";
$searchfor = ($_POST['name']);

if ($searchfor !=""){
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/\b.*$pattern.*\b/i"; 

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found matches For Player ".$searchfor.":\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No matches found For Player ".$searchfor."";
}
}
else{
  echo "No Name Imput";
  }

?>
```

Now what i currently need to do is to make 2 logsearches to be able to grab logs for both players is it possible to just type in Turks as the first variable and Dannys as the second and than search the log and for example make their text a different color?

Hopefully you guys can assist me

Greetings Glenn

EDIT : What i currently have is this

http://gyazo.com/997e6e5bd50cccedb7f6439b013c0c85

So what i basically want is to grab the entire log search for 2 names than mark them with a color
New Code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
white-space:pre-wrap;
font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
$now = ($_POST['date']);
$player = ($_POST['player']);
$player2 = ($_POST['player2']);
$player3 = ($_POST['player3']);
$player4 = ($_POST['player4']);
$player5 = ($_POST['player5']);


if ($player != ""){
$handle = fopen("logs/server_log_".$now.".txt", "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote($player) ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: red;\">$0</span>", $line) . '';
        if ($player2 !=""){
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote($player2) ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: blue;\">$0</span>", $line) . '';
        }
        if ($player3 !=""){
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote($player3) ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: yellow;\">$0</span>", $line) . '';
        }
        if ($player4 !=""){
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote($player4) ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: green;\">$0</span>", $line) . '';
        }
        if ($player5 !=""){
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote($player5) ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: purple;\">$0</span>", $line) . '';
        }
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error in opening the file.";
}
}
else {
echo "You must fill in 1 player name";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Apperently if you fill in more variables it doubles the entire text how can i do it so the text only shows up once and not 5 times

Comment: You may want to give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword

Comment: Thanks i will take a look but im quit bad with these type of codes :p

Comment: Hmmm im kinda wondering how i can implement it so it just grabs the entire file than highlights the 2 players names

Comment: Loop all the file lines and use what you see in that link.

Comment: Well GiamPY im trying but im quite inexperienced with these type of codes possibly all my questions on stackoverflow are about these type of scripts could you maybe help me with a little example?

Comment: [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20935460/2362433)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it:

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");

if ($handle)
{
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
    {
        echo preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote('Turks') ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: red;\">$0</span>", $line) . '<br/>';
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error in opening the file.";
}
```

Comment: ok looks interesting do you think you could adjust my script a little cause i tried putting it in but it didnt really work

Comment: Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in logsearch2.php on line 8 i get this error

Comment: You don't need to use file_get_contents.

Comment: ok but it seems i get an error with your script do you know why?

Comment: I tried it myself in my localhost and it worked perfectly, maybe there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: i just direclty copied what you gave put it in PHP but it seems to not work

Comment: I still need to figure this out im trying to replace $player with turks but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Just change `preg_quote('Turks')` with `preg_quote($searchfor)`.

Comment: Alright is it possible that if it doesnt match anything in the file to return an error?

Comment: The code I gave you is only for code highlighting. Use `strpos()` to do that ([link](http://www.php.net/function.strpos)).

Comment: Giampy how would i do this with several variables i have tried it but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Ive added the new code it seems when i add more variables it doubles the amount of text based on given variables

Comment: Because you're doing it wrong. Just follow my code and modify it to `preg_replace("/\w*?". preg_quote('word1') ."|". preg_quote('word2') ."\w*/i", "<span style=\"color: red;\">$0</span>", $line)` - basically add a `|` and then add the other word you wish to search.

Comment: No, no. You just need to modify the pattern.

Comment: What im basically trying to do is to have 5 variables but all highlighted with different colors is that possible

Comment: This question has went too far already - you should not use stackoverflow as somewhere to request scripts. Nevertheless, the original question has been answered. For your new question, please open a new one.