# To highlight text in a string in php

Tags: php, regex

Since I am beginner, Please help to resolve this. I have tried with the following code to highlight the text in a string, but I don't get the expected result.

```
foreach($modules as $comments)
    {
        foreach($block_words as $k=>$v)
        {

          foreach($v as $n)
          {
            $comments['Updated'] = (preg_replace("/\b($n)\b/i","<b>$n</b>",$comments['Updated']));  
          }

        }
    }
```

I have used this, but getting the output
`What <b>you</b> trying <b>to</b> say.................. Plz <b>clear</b> and Neetttttttttt`

Please find the error and help me to get the solution.

Comment: What is your input and expected result?

Comment: $block_words=Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [word] => to
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [word] => you
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [word] => clear
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [word] => good
        )

) and $comments['updated']='string..........array';

I want to show the block words highlighted if it occurs in $comments['updated']

Comment: Check these links. It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword
----
http://www.phpro.org/articles/Highlight-Search-Words.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
   /*** quote the text for regex ***/
   $n = preg_quote($n);
   /*** highlight the words ***/
   $comments['Updated'] = preg_replace("/\b($n)\b/i", '<b>\1</b>', $comments['Updated']);
```

**EDIT**

It is the working code that I have used.

```
  $sentence = "What you are trying to say?";
  $wordsToHighlight = array("you", "to");
  $modifiedrawData = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $wordsToHighlight).'/i', '<span style="color:green;"><b>$0</b></span>', $sentence);
  echo $modifiedrawData;
```

According to your example, assuming `$v` contains the words you want to highlight.

```
 $comments['Updated'] = preg_replace('/'.implode('|', $v).'/i', '<span style="color:green;"><b>$0</b></span>', $sentence);
```

Comment: Yes i tried this but i am getting it as What <b></b> trying <b></b> say.................. Plz <b></b> and Neetttttttttt . This is the original string What you trying to say.................. Plz clear and Neetttttttttt. pls suggest me the solution to solve this

Comment: @Developer Please try the code in the Edit section. I have also used this code for highlighting words and it's working fine, so it must work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but i am getting the stirng as it is. What you trying to say.................. Plz clear and Neetttttttttt

Comment: @Developer I have added an example

Comment: Is it possible to highlight text in texarea.

Comment: @Developer yes. Add the content between `div` tag like `<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable>htmlTEXT</div>`. For more info, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea). Plus, did this answer worked?

Comment: Yes got the answer. Thank u

Comment: @Developer, you're welcome. Please upvote it and mark it right.

Comment: If i want to apply the above highlight concept to text area how can i apply to text area in php