# find and color a string in another string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a String, let's say:

```
$needle = "HELLO";
```

And I have another String I want to find $needle in, let's say:

```
$haystack = "HELLO WORLD";
```

I know there are methods which return the position as an int etc.
but how could I then color that very string when it's being output?
I made myself an array with some chars in it which are being output randomly like 2000 times and I'd like to see them in color when they make up the right word.

Comment: Your question would really be improved with a bit of code for context, and a more specific explanation of exactly what you're trying to make that code do instead of whatever it's currently doing.

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php, or http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. The method you are describing sounds like the first. Pull the characters until the match, then serve the match with the style parameters appended and post pended. Depending on where you are outputting this coloring options will vary.

Comment: Maybe a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time

Comment: @chris85 Yes, actually it might be. Shall I delete my question?

Comment: Looks like you already selected an answer so I don't think deleting is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've interpreted your question as:

> I want to find a string within another string, making the matching characters a different colour in the output

Easiest method would be

```
<style>.myclass { color: red; }</style>
<?php

$needle = "HELLO";
$haystack = "HELLO WORLD";

$myOutput = str_replace($needle,"<a class='myclass'>".$needle."</a>",$haystack);

echo $myOutput;

?>
```

Obviously editing it to suit the method you're intending for it, but the above should help with one possible solution.