# PHP - Bolding certain text within t

Tags: php, html, css, drupal

```
$need_it_sooner = l(
    t('Need it sooner? Click here'), 
    'need-it-sooner', array(
    'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('float-right', 'button', 'button-red'),
            'style' => 'float:right;',
        ))
    );
```

Here's the code I have, I'd like it to display

> **Need it sooner?** Click here.

Would I be able to style the text easily within the t() or would I have to write another big chunk to accomplish this?

Comment: Add `font-weight: bold;` to the `'style'` attribute maybe?

Comment: Can you post the `l` and `t` source code?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highlight the word in the string, if it contains the keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483844/highlight-the-word-in-the-string-if-it-contains-the-keyword)

Comment: Try this one `t('<span style="font-weight: bold;">'.'Need it sooner?'.'</span>'.' Click here'),`

Comment: Are you using Drupal?

Comment: yes this is with drupal @NinaLisitsinskaya

Comment: I think you should point this out in your question. `l` and `t` are the Drupal functions, not just the PHP functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the Drupal 7 the function `l` takes an array of options as the third parameter. If you pass it the option `'html' => TRUE`, it can accept HTML.
Also you can pass HTML through the function `t`. So you can try to do it this way:

```
$need_it_sooner = l(
    t('<strong>Need it sooner?</strong> Click here'), 
    'need-it-sooner', array(
    'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('float-right', 'button', 'button-red'),
            'style' => 'float:right;',
        ),
    'html' => TRUE)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `l()` function is advised, but if you have some specific request consider other options. I.e.

```
$need_it_sooner = '<a href="'.url('need-it-sooner').'" ><strong>'.t('Need it sooner?').'</strong> '.t('Click here').'</a>';
```

Writing this code from my head so there can be some mistake, but that's the idea. Use 2 `t()` calls to translate text separately. And avoid embedding css if you can.